# What typescript type do I use with useRef() hook when setting current manually?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How can I use a React ref as a mutable instance, with Typescript? The current property appears to be typed as read-only.

I am using React + Typescript to develop a library that interacts with input fields that are NOT rendered by React. I want to capture a reference to the HTML element and then bind React events to it.

```
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  const { elementId, handler } = props;

  // Bind change handler on mount/ unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (inputRef.current === null) {
      throw new Exception(`Input with ID attribute ${elementId} not found`);
    }
    handler(inputRef.current.value);

    const callback = debounce((e) => {
      eventHandler(e, handler);
    }, 200);

    inputRef.current.addEventListener('keypress', callback, true);

    return () => {
      inputRef.current.removeEventListener('keypress', callback, true);
    };
  });
```

It generates compiler errors: `semantic error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.`

I also tried `const inputRef = useRef<{ current: HTMLInputElement }>();` This lead to this compiler error:

```
Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type '{ current: HTMLInputElement; } | undefined'.

  Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ current: HTMLInputElement; } | undefined'.
```

Comment: I think `HTMLInputElement` is correct, but inputRef should be set to `null` initially, `useRef<HTMLInputElement(null)`

Comment: I thought so too. That works if ref is captured during React's render - `<input ref={myRef} />` - not setting `myRef.current = ...`

Comment: This might help: 
 https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31065#issuecomment-446660394 specifically `ref7`

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Yeah, this is a quirk of how the typings are written:

```
function useRef<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;
function useRef<T>(initialValue: T | null): RefObject<T>;
```

- If the type of the `initialValue` and type parameter `T` match, you'll hit the first override and get a `MutableRefObject<T>`.
- If the type of the `initialValue` includes `null` and type parameter `T` doesn't, you'll hit the second override and get an immutable `RefObject<T>`.

You're hitting the second case when you're doing this:

```
useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

`T` is specified as `HTMLInputElement` and the *type* of `null` is inferred as `HTMLInputElement | null`.

You can hit the first case by doing this:

```
useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)
```

`T` is specified as `HTMLInputElement | null` and the *type* of `null` is inferred as `HTMLInputElement | null`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a ton of sense and got my code to compile. I used `const inputRef = useRef<HTMLElement | null>(null);` to avoid a compiler error from `inputRef.current = document.getElementById(elementId);`  Not sure if that's worth an edit.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need any input-specific properties from the ref, then I'd do what you did and broaden the type you annotate the ref with; if you do need input-specific properties, I'd probably do `getElementById(elementId) as HTMLInputElement` before assigning.

Comment: as an fyi to anyone else I found this couldn't be done without the useRef hook, createRef wouldn't allow it. Maybe there could be a way but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for variable (assigned in a useEffect) `const shaderMat: React.RefObject<THREE.ShaderMaterial|null> = useRef(null);` doesn't allow me to do `shaderMat.current = mat;` because curretn is read-only.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier You've explicitly annotated `shaderMat` to be a `RefObject`, which is the immutable type, so yeah, it's not going to let you mutate it in a useEffect.  You need to use the type params for `useRef` to control the type, not an annotation on the variable itself.

Comment: @Retsam Was confused on the first part of your response, I just realized you type a generic parameter on `useRef` function, and not the `RefObject` type.

Comment: I am getting the following error for you line `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')`

Answer (score 16):

`as` key.

You can use it like this for input component.

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
```

Comment: why casting if you useRef provides generic type

Comment: you are right, there is no need for that. edited thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I came to this question by searching how to type `useRef` with Typescript when used with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. The accepted answer helped me solve that.

You can declare your timeout/interval like this

```
const myTimeout = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null>(null)
```

And to clear it and set it again, you do it as usual:

```
const handleChange = () => {
  if (myTimeout.current) {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout.current)
  }
  myTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
    doSomething()
  }, 500)
}
```

The typing will work both if you're running in Node or in a Browser.

Comment: This answer is more appropriate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65638439/type-for-useref-if-used-with-setinterval-react-typescript where it has similar answers.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write code like this:

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

and when you need to use it you have to write it like this:

```
inputRef.current?.focus();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).