# type for useRef if used with setInterval, react-typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, next.js, settimeout

I am doing a simple animation in a next.js app.

```
let flipInterval = useRef();



const startAnimation = () => {
    flipInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
      setIsFlipping((prevFlipping) => !prevFlipping);
    }, 10000);
  };
```

for `flipInterval.current` I am getting "Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'undefined'". So i checked how to use Timeout type, I see that people are using  but thats not working.

```
 let flipInterval = useRef<typeof window.settimeout>();
```

I also passed number `useRef<number>()` this time I am getting "Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'"

this did not work neither

```
  let flipInterval = useRef<typeof window.setInterval>();
```

Comment: setInterval return an id for clearing the timer. You shouldn't store this in a ref.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If you just want to clear the interval when the component is removed, then you should use `useEffect()` that returns a cleanup function.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you need to pass the proper return value type of `setInterval`. for this use `ReturnType`:

```
const flipInterval = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | null>(null)
```

Comment: I get a new error after applying this though: `Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.ts (2540)`

Comment: Solved by doing `useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | null>(null)` or alternatively `useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval>>()`

Answer (score 16):

```
 const intervalRef: { current: NodeJS.Timeout | null } = useRef(null);


const startAnimation = () => {
   const id = setInterval(() => {
       setIsFlipping((prevFlipping) => !prevFlipping);
   }, 10000);
      intervalRef.current = id;
 };

  const clear = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current as NodeJS.Timeout);
  };
```

Answer (score 14):

How i'm using
*It is preferable to set initialValue of useRef. Thats why null.

```
  const timeout = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);

  timeout.current = setTimeout(() => someAction()), 500);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout.current as NodeJS.Timeout);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are debouncing and need to clear a timeout `null` needs to be handled

Posting as this might help others due to the title of the question.

```
const flipInterval:{current: NodeJS.Timeout | null} = useRef(null)

const startAnimation = () => {
  flipInterval.current && clearTimeout(scrollTimeout.current);
        
  flipInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
    setIsFlipping((prevFlipping) => !prevFlipping)
  }, 10000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let flipInterval = useRef<number | null>(null);
const startAnimation = () => {
  flipInterval.current = window.setInterval(() => {
    setIsFlipping((prevFlipping) => !prevFlipping);
  }, 10000);
};

/* way of clear interval */
window.clearInterval(flipInterval.current || 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NodeJS.Timeout` type:

```
let flipInterval = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>()

const startAnimation = () => {
  flipInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
    setIsFlipping((prevFlipping) => !prevFlipping)
  }, 10000)
}
```