# JavaScript On-click Function to start and stop Intervals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, setinterval

I have two onclick functions that performing start and stop functions using socket when i click start it start requesting images from server(i am using intervals) when i click stop the server is stopped but the request keep coming to the server. the intervals seems not stopped after clicking kindly review my code

Code:

```
  var interval;
  
  function onclick() {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      socket.emit("get_image", "Click");
      socket.on('send_image', (message) => {
        setImage(message.image); 
      });
    }, 350)
  }

  function onclicks() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    setImage(blanked);

  }
```

I have tried to add clearInterval function but it seems not working

Comment: or a `ref`, interval is being redefined on each render.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type for useRef if used with setInterval, react-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65638439/type-for-useref-if-used-with-setinterval-react-typescript)

Comment: `const [interval,setInterval] = useState(null)`, instead of `var interval`. And change `interval = ..` to `setInterval(..)`

Comment: ref is more appropriate @sagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared at the top level of a component are redeclared on each render (here every time you call `setImage()`) so `interval` is undefined by the time `onclicks()` is called.

In order to maintain the value through renders you need to either use `state` ([useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)) or a `ref` ([useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)) which won't lose it's value. In this case, since you don't want renders attached to the value of `interval` a `ref` is more appropriate. `useRef()` returns an object with a `current` property in which your value will be stored.

```
const interval = React.useRef(null);
  
function onclick() {
  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    socket.emit("get_image", "Click");
    socket.on('send_image', (message) => {
      setImage(message.image); 
    });
  }, 350);
}

function onclicks() {
  clearInterval(interval.current);
  interval.current = null; // reset the ref
  setImage(blanked);
}
```

You probably also want to avoid setting multiple intervals. You may already be doing so, but if not you can check if `interval` is null or not before setting a new one.

```
const interval = React.useRef(null);
  
function onclick() {
  if (interval.current === null) { // only set new interval if interval ref is null
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      socket.emit("get_image", "Click");
      socket.on('send_image', (message) => {
        setImage(message.image); 
      });
    }, 350);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest way to solve this behavior was set the interval as a **Ref**:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

// Initialize the interval ref
const interval = useRef();

// Create the interval
function onclick() {
   interval.current = setInterval(() => {
     socket.emit("get_image", "Click");
     socket.on('send_image', (message) => {
     setImage(message.image); 
   });
 }, 350)
}

// Remove the interval
function onclicks() {
  clearInterval(interval.current);
  setImage(blanked);
}
```

Using this *hook*, the component will not re-render when you change the value remove/change the interval.