# how to call setInterval on button click in React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I try to write a program that increments counter when user press **Start** and stop incrementing it when user press **Stop**

[Output should looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf12O.png)

and then it should be

**XXX-0-XXX**

**XXX-1-XXX**

**XXX-2-XXX**
....

the process should stop when **Stop** is pressed.

The code (which does not work):

```
import React from 'react'

import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0)
  const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = React.useState(null)

  const increment = () => {
    const nextCounter = counter + 1
    setCounter(nextCounter)
  }

  const onClickStart = () => {
    setIntervalID(setInterval(increment, 100))
  }

  const onClickStop = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID)
    setIntervalID(null)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>XXX-{counter}-XXX</label>
      <button onClick={onClickStart}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={onClickStop}>Stop</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

the issue that after this

**XXX-1-XXX**

is shown, and then everything stops. increment is called, but counter is not incremented.

I looked at the similar questions, but found none where setInterval is called from a button click. It looks like I do not understand something obvious. So any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

My question is not answered here:

[JavaScript On-click Function to start and stop Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740863/javascript-on-click-function-to-start-and-stop-intervals)

that is a similar question, but it does not answer my question.

The answer for my question is written by Dennis Kats and the answer is to fix increment function:

```
    const increment = () => setCounter(oldCounter => oldCounter + 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your increment function creates a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the `counter` variable, and `setInterval` executes the initial `increment` function, where `counter` is always still 0, every time. As a result, the `setInterval` repeatedly sets the counter to 1. You can read more about closures in React [here](https://medium.com/swlh/javascript-closures-and-react-4c0e3f705a6c) if you're not familiar with them.

In the meantime, to fix your code, `setCounter` can optionally take in a function that maps from the current value (even after state updates) to what the next value should be. This way, `increment` doesn't actually close over the counter state, but receives it as dynamically through `setCounter`, and so it is able to properly increment the value.

Here is a working example:

```js
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0)
  const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = React.useState(null)

  // here is the primary change!!
  // we simply tell setCounter to add 1 to the old counter value
  const increment = () => setCounter(oldCounter => oldCounter + 1);

  const onClickStart = () => {
    if (intervalID === null) // small fix to prevent starting multiple intervals
      setIntervalID(setInterval(increment, 100));
  }

  const onClickStop = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    setIntervalID(null);
  }

  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <label>XXX-{counter}-XXX</label>
      <button onClick={onClickStart}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={onClickStop}>Stop</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render( < App / > );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - it works, and I understood what the issue was, and I almost understand how it is fixed. The only thing that I do not understand is "const increment = () => setCounter(oldCounter => oldCounter + 1);" How is it working? increment is function without parameter that calls function setCounter(oldCounter). But where does oldCounter comes from?

Comment: Now understand. Apparently I should have read this https://medium.com/ableneo/typing-of-react-hooks-in-typescript-947b200fa0b0 first. Especially "SetStateAction type is similar to the overloaded type of initialProps. The user of the function can set the state directly or use the function with the previous state as an argument." So thanks, now everything is clear