# clearInterval() fails to stop an interval running on a timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

First time using `clearInterval()` looking at other examples and the interval docs this appears to be the way to stop an interval. Not sure what I am missing.

The intention is to kill the timer when the `currentStop` prop updates.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type Props = {
  stopNumber: number;
  currentStop: number;
};

const timerComponent = ({ stopNumber, currentStop }: Props) => {
  let interval: NodeJS.Timer;

  // Update elapsed on a timer
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stopNumber === currentStop) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('timer is running');
      }, 3000);

      // Clear interval on unmount
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, []);

  // Clear timers that were running
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stopNumber !== currentStop) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [currentStop]);
};
```

Comment: @pilchard yes, looks like not using `useRef()` was my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the intervalId on a ref instead

```js
const timerComponent = ({ stopNumber, currentStop }: Props) => {
  const intervalRef = useRef({
    intervalId: 0
  })

  // Update elapsed on a timer
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stopNumber === currentStop) {
      intervalRef.current.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('timer is running');
      }, 3000);

      // Clear interval on unmount
      return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current.intervalId);
    }
  }, []);

  // Clear timers that were running
  useEffect(() => {
    if (stopNumber !== currentStop) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current.intervalId);
    }
  }, [currentStop]);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! for reference: [Assigning type to useRef for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68369590/8890753)

Answer (score 1):

Use a ref to store the interval id instead.

```js
let interval = useRef();
// to start the setInterval:
interval.current = setInterval(...);
// to stop the setInterval:
clearInterval(interval.current);
```